# ActionBar and tabs not displaying properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-xml

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s0g7.png) is what my app is showing

You can see that the action bar and tab layout at the top are both white. For some reason they are being set to my color backgroundColor. I want them to be set to primaryColor. How do I do this?

Here is my code:

main xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.mddri_.myeats.main._MainActivity">



<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    />
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout"/>
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mddri_.myeats">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

    <activity android:name=".main.MainActivity">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".viewdatabase.ViewDatabase">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".viewmeals.ViewMeals" />
    <activity android:name=".viewkitchen.ViewKitchen" />
    <activity
        android:name=".main._MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity___main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

styles:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat"> <!--.Light.DarkActionBar-->
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColor</item>
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/textColor</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
</style>
<style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

colors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#C0FF3E</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#04a314</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#8a9b8c</color>
<color name="textColor">#555555</color>
<color name="background">#fcfcfc</color>
</resources>
```

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? I set the background color for both the actionbar and tablayout to be colorPrimary, but it's still showing up as the colorbackground

Comment: try check `app:theme` in the Tablayout or if there's is any background item in the `app`

Comment: Are you using the Support Library? if so, can you tell me if you have a `app_bar_main.xml` in your layouts folder?

Comment: I do not have an `app_bar_main.xml` in my layouts folder, I'm pretty sure i'm using the Support Library